# Convert an EnumSet to an array of integers

Tags: java, android, arrays, enums, enumset

I have an EnumSet and want to convert it to array of its ordinal values.
For example:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C; }
EnumSet enumSet = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C);
```

and what I want to get:

```
[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the raw type EnumSet without the `<MyEnum>` part

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> enumSet = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C);
```

A Java 8 solution:

```
MyEnum[] values = MyEnum.values();
int[] ordinals = IntStream.range(0, values.length).filter(i -> enumSet.contains(values[i])).toArray();
```

A pre-Java 8 solution:

```
int[] ordinals2 = new int[enumSet.size()];
int index = 0;
for (MyEnum e : enumSet)
    ordinals2[index++] = e.ordinal();
```

Check that it worked:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ordinals));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ordinals2));
```

Comment: I think I need to use pre-Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with streams:

```
 int[] ordinals = enumSet.stream().mapToInt(Enum::ordinal).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but in Android there is no stream() method. I'm sorry, I forgot to add `Android` tag