# Convert between EnumSet and array of boolean values

Tags: java, list, enums, boolean, enumset

I have an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and want to convert back-and-forth to/from an array of boolean primitives. If it works better, I could work with a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of an array, and/or [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) objects rather than boolean primitives.

```
enum MyEnum { DOG, CAT, BIRD; }
EnumSet enumSet = EnumSet.of( MyEnum.DOG, MyEnum.CAT );
```

What I want to get on the other end is an array that looks like this:

```
[TRUE, TRUE, FALSE]
```

This Question here is similar to this one, [Convert an EnumSet to an array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32976896/642706). Differences:

- boolean or `Boolean` versus integers (obviously)
- I want all members of the enum to be represented, with a `TRUE` for each enum element included in the `EnumSet` and a `FALSE` for each element that is excluded from the `EnumSet`. The other Question’s array includes only the items found in the `EnumSet`. (more importantly)

Answer (score 6):

To do that you'd basically write

```
MyEnum[] values = MyEnum.values(); // or MyEnum.class.getEnumConstants()
boolean[] present = new boolean[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  present[i] = enumSet.contains(values[i]);
}
```

Going the other direction, from boolean array `present` created above to `enumSet_` created below.

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> enumSet_ = EnumSet.noneOf ( MyEnum.class );  // Instantiate an empty EnumSet.
MyEnum[] values_ = MyEnum.values ();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < values_.length ; i ++ ) {
    if ( present[ i ] ) {  // If the array element is TRUE, add the matching MyEnum item to the EnumSet. If FALSE, do nothing, effectively omitting the matching MyEnum item from the EnumSet.
        enumSet_.add ( values_[ i ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was curious about the fancier lambda/streams syntax but it is good to show the simple-but-sure old-fashioned syntax.

Comment: I took the liberty of writing example code for going the other direction, from array to EnumSet. This code is based on some working code of mine, but modified to match your example here. So I'm not 100% if my code posted here is correct.

Comment: @BasilBourque, what is `QuarterHour`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Oops, that `QuarterHour` was a copy-paste carry-over error from [this Answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38368468/642706) for another Question. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

For the present, I don't see a better solution than

```
Boolean[] b = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).map(set::contains).toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

To get an `EnumSet` from an array of `boolean` primitives by using [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/4922375)

```
MyEnum[] enums = zip(Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()), Arrays.stream(b),
    (e, b) -> b ? e : null).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(MyEnum[]::new);
```

Comment: The contains method won't iterate over the whole enum. The contains method is overridden in both of the EnumSet implementations, JumboEnumSet and RegularEnumSet.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you could do it like this

```
List<Boolean> present = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).map(enumSet::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To go the other way around you could do something like this

```
IntStream.range(0, present.size()).filter(present::get).mapToObj(i -> MyEnum.values()[i]).
    collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class)));
```